# ESP32 running I2C in ISR (non-negotiable) keeps breaking

Tags: interrupt, esp32, i2c, arduino-ide, adc

I've been writing writing C code on AVR for years (no arduino, just a makefile). However I need to do something bigger, so I chose an ESP32 Feather S3 board and interfaced it with my own board.

I'm trying to read an I2C ADC (ADS1115). I HAVE TO do it on a timer since I'll be passing those samples through FIR filters and they have to hit the proper real life frequencies. Unfortunately everyone seems to say that this is impossible.

The I2C has 2 channels connected and I need to take a sample every 100ms (10Hz). The chip is more than capable of that, but I need to send a I2C command for the mux to switch channels and then to get a sample. So this requires AT LEAST ONE I2C command in the ISR. The optimal would be 3 (change mux, start conversion, read raw value).

Here's the relevant interrupt:

```
#include <ADS1115_WE.h>

#define SERIAL_DEBUG

#define _TIMERINTERRUPT_LOGLEVEL_     4
#include "ESP32TimerInterrupt.h"

#define TIMER0_INTERVAL_MS        100
ESP32Timer ITimer0(1);

ADS1115_WE adc = ADS1115_WE(0x48);

...

bool IRAM_ATTR TimerHandler0(void * timerNo)
{
    static bool toggle0 = false;
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, toggle0);
    toggle0 = !toggle0;

        adc.setCompareChannels(ADS1115_COMP_0_GND);

    return true;
}


#define TIMER0_INTERVAL_MS        100
ESP32Timer ITimer0(1);

void setup() {

...

  Serial.begin(19200);
  Wire.begin();

  adc.init();
  adc.setConvRate(ADS1115_475_SPS);
  adc.setVoltageRange_mV(ADS1115_RANGE_2048);
  adc.setMeasureMode(ADS1115_SINGLE);
  adc.setCompareChannels(ADS1115_COMP_0_GND);
  adc.setAlertPinToConversionReady();

...

 ITimer0.attachInterruptInterval(TIMER0_INTERVAL_MS * 1000, TimerHandler0);

}
```

Just to be clear. The ADC works outside the interrupts. The TFT display works fine. Serial communication works fine. The problem starts when I throw a single I2C transaction into the ISR. The board resets after a second or two.

I really can't "just use a semaphore in the ISR and run the I2C code in the main loop" - The time it takes to update the TFT display would introduce immense jitter in the sampling rate.

So... can it be done?

Comment: What's the specific error/exception you're getting? If it's not allowing I2C interrupt operations within an interrupt handle, have you considered using bit bang I2C instead?

Comment: Maybe the problem is not with the adc setting call. I'm not aware that you could return anything from an ISR(), it should be `void ISR()` instead of `bool ISR()`, and an `ISR()` won't return anything. BTW, the first 3 lines of the code `static bool toggle0 = false; digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, toggle0); toggle0 = !toggle0;` could be written as a one-liner `digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, !digitalRead(LED_BUILTIN));`.

Comment: "update the TFT display would introduce immense jitter", that's why setting `piority` of each task exist and that's only happened if your display has higher or equal priority as the ADC task.